# iphone development - Testing App on real device with PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, iphone, mysql

I developed an iPhone application which uses some PHP code and a MySQL database. To test this app in a real device, does Apple provide a webserver on iOS or not? In my code I am running PHP code using URLs like this:

http://localhost/GetUserlist.php

So, to test this in a real device, does Apple provide a webserver or not? Do we need to host our own files in our own server for this?

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

There is no implemented web server on the iPhone and Apple does not provide such services for developers. You need to host the PHP/MySQL on your own server.

Comment: You mean i need to host PHP files on external webserver and i need to use that link on my application. Please correct me if iam wrong

Answer (score 0):

I've thought about this a dozen times already but I haven't tried anything so far. I'm pretty sure using PHP/MySQL is a no-go on an iPhone, I think you should host these files somewhere else and basically export the data in JSON or XML. Then you could use a mobile javascript framework to get the data and use it within your application.

PhoneGap is one of these frameworks, I also believe that using jQuery/jQuery Mobile can be done without any problems together with PhoneGap... Furthermore PhoneGap gives you the ability to use CSS/HTML for the design.

On the other hand: if PHP/SQL is really what you need (and thus also an internet connection), why not just create an online app/website for mobile phones? In my opinion it's only worth creating an app if you save data locally on the mobile phone to access even without a working internet connection.

Comment: This is an social ntworking application which wecant use local database, coz multiple users will be accessing Mysql Database. And Thisphp scrip using oly to pull data from Mysql in XML output format

Comment: Then why would you use an application? Most mobile phones can add icons on the screen linking to a webpage.. Imho the strength of a real app is being able to access it while offline, if that's not needed, why bother making it harder for yourself by making the app instead of creating a mobile site.